# How to make a 3D cube using a triangle mesh with the help of Python

Tags: python

Consider:

[image: A cube of some kind]

How can I make this cube (look at the picture) in Python and then export the coordinates in a .obj (stores all the coordinates/information about 3d objects) file?

Is there any working project I can follow?

Comment: What is a .obj file? In a particular format? For a particular application? .obj would normally be executable content, not data. Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70521713/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now).

Comment: At least share the result of your research.

Comment: @PeterMortensen there's no *normally* about `.obj` format, it's a standard [data format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) for representation of geometry

Comment: I haven't done a research yet I'm new to this and I want to know if it's achievable via python or not. I did have a look at some github projects where people have made 3D objects using Triangle Mesh and I want to make one as well but those projects doesn't export the co ordinates in an obj instead they use .vtk format which I don't want. So that is why I'm looking a way to find out any ways to make 3D objects with triangle mesh via python and export it to .obj.

Comment: There's plenty to find by googling `python write to .obj file`. But first you need to generate the vertices (3D positions) and indices (which vertices are connected in triangles)

Comment: thats exactly I wanted to find. Can you please help me generate those 3d positions after generating I think we can work on the export part.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.